# I can't open a new tab with JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have a little problem regarding my code in wordpress. I am using a gravityform plugin in wordpress. But it seems that I cannot set it to open a new tab after I clicked the "submit" button. 
below is the bottom properties when being inspect:

```
<input type="submit" id="gform_submit_button_5" class="button gform_button" value="Submit" tabindex="10">
```

I tried all the javascript here in stackoverflow but it didn't work.. :(

This is the code I used to call button to open in new tab.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
       jQuery(function() {
       jQuery(".gform_submit_button_5").attr( 'target', '_blank');
       });
</script>
```

Comment: this is not your issue but your selector is wrong, should be: "#gform_submit_button_5"

Answer (score 1):

You should add target="_blank" to your `<form>` element and not on the button. Can you please try that see ?

Comment: I can't add taget="_blank directly to the gravity form because it is a plugin and there was no file when I go to editor. :(

Answer (score 1):

try that:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QAm2b/)

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#gform_submit_button_5").attr( 'formtarget', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: this ones worked. but the link is redirected to this page http://www.caring-people-home-healthcare.com/#gf_5..

by the way, this is my site: 
http://www.caring-people-home-healthcare.com/

There was an image above the footer that has a Brochure title. when you click the image, a form popups. that's the form that i am working right now.